# Get Zipcodes List by giving my current point zipcode inside a radius

Tags: zipcode

I need to find if the given zip code is within the required radius. For example, if the user has entered 20910, it should be able to determine if it's within 5 mile radius of 20814. Is there a way to do it? Google API or something? Please help.

I'm using C# as the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called the havershine formula...

[Havershine Example - google it for more](http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/)